# Would Code Review be a good site to post architectural issues?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I have a question that involves some code, however it's more of an architectural question and I'm torn whether to post it on Code Review or Stack Overflow.  I feel like it may be a bit of a grey area, and I'm leaning towards posting it on Code Review.  Would this be an acceptable use of the Code Review site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> and your question is not about … Higher-level architecture and design of software systems

Architecture is specifically off-topic on Code Review. This is a site for reviewing at a lower level. If the purpose of a question is to review the architecture, it is better on SO or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).